# Trying to prevent an email address username appearing as mail-to in email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am generating an email using Razor which notifies the end user of the username which is in email address format. The Razor view produces the following text:

```
Username is: sam@interpulse.co.uk
```

Unfortunately when this is opened, Outlook marks it up as a link and as a "mail-to" link. This also messes up my text formatting, since it thinks it is a link. How can I prevent this? It is really only text, nothing more.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Add before email address, and remember to escape Razor @ symbol.

```
<font style="display: none;">@@</font>
```

Comment: Check out the work-around in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2292473/141172.  That may or may not work in any other email client.

Comment: Thanks, see Edit, I needed to tweak it for Razor. Make it an answer and I will mark it so.

Comment: I don't have anything to add other than the link, so probably best to close this question as a dup pointing to the other one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I stop Outlook from rendering an email address as a mailto: link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110825/how-do-i-stop-outlook-from-rendering-an-email-address-as-a-mailto-link)

Comment: For reference we have now found out that this does not work for Gmail. One sees the "@" sign, so have had to remove it.