# Prevent email clients from auto-highlighting email addresses with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, apple-mail

I am looking for a CSS/HTML workaround to prevent email clients such as Outlook and Apple Mail from auto-highlighting an email address in my HTML emails.

My markup is:

`<p>To ensure that our messages are sent straight to your inbox and not your junk or bulk email folders please add crmpicco@crmpicco.co.uk to your address book</p>`

and Outlook (and Apple Mail) presents this as this:
[image: outlook-auto-highlight-email]

I have tried wrapping the email address in an `<a>` and setting `text-decoration: none`, but Outlook seems to ignore this (I haven't tested that with Apple Mail)

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Maybe this can do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110825/how-do-i-stop-outlook-from-rendering-an-email-address-as-a-mailto-link

Comment: The happens on the email client end. It parses a message and when it finds a match, makes the change after the fact. The only way around this would be to make it not fit the format of an email address e.g. an image.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, I think an image would be a workaround of sorts...but it's too "spammy"

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal fix for this since different email clients handle email addresses in plain text differently. Although you are on the right track with wrapping the address in your own html since the client will not do it.

To the best of my knowledge, Outlook does not remove styling on `<a>` tags, so this should work there as well.

```
<a href="mailto:address@example.com" style="text-decoration:none;">address@example.com</a>
```

I recommend getting an account at [litmus.com](http://www.litmus.com) where you will be able to use their email builder (it´s really an html editor in the browser) and get instant previews of 30+ email clients (3 after the trial period) while editing the email. The editor alone is worth a look.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This doesn't work in Outlook 2013.

Comment: Have you tried also adding the color: definition with the same color as the text? If that works then the only difference visible will be the underlining of the email address. Are you adding the style directly inline or in a <style> tag? Inlining all css is the absolute best practice for emails, even for responsive designs.

Answer (score -1):

Tested in Outlook (Office16)

Try pressing [Tab] in an e-mail message. It will select the next hyperlink. With   the e-mail address selected, it is now easy to copy it to the clipboard without triggering a new mail.

For me, this makes the auto-hyperlink-behaviour of the mail client a lot less annoying.